# Dropwizard/Jersey is giving "Unable to process JSON" message on GET request

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, dropwizard

I'm trying to make my first simple project with Dropwizard. I have a MySQL-database, and the idea is to get the data (companies) from there and represent it as JSON. I have followed the [Getting started](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/0.6.2/getting-started.html) page by Dropwizard and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-dropwizard-connecting-to-a-da) tutorial to get connected to database with Hibernate.

The idea is that URL "/companies" serves all the companies as JSON, and it is working fine.

URL "/companies/{id}" is supposed to give a single company with given id, but every request gives code 400 and message "Unable to process JSON". The details field in the response says

> "No serializer found for class
>   jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Present and no properties
>   discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )"

If I give an id of company that does not exist in database, the class in mentioned message changes to

> jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Absent

The company class is here:

```
public class Company {
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "zipcode")
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String eMail;

    @Column(name = "mobile")
    private String mobile;

    public Company() {

    }

    public Company (String name, String address, String zipCode, String eMail, String mobile) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String geteMail() {
        return eMail;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void seteMail(String eMail) {
        this.eMail = eMail;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

 }
```

DAO is here:

```
public class CompanyDAO extends AbstractDAO<Company> {

    public CompanyDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }
    public List<Company> findAll() {
        return list(namedQuery("com.webapp.project.core.Company.findAll"));
    }

    public Optional<Company> findById(long id) {
        return Optional.fromNullable(get(id));
    }
}
```

Application class:

```
public class HelloWorldApplication extends Application<HelloWorldConfiguration> {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new HelloWorldApplication().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "hello-world";
    }
    /**
     * Hibernate bundle.
     */
    private final HibernateBundle<HelloWorldConfiguration> hibernateBundle
            = new HibernateBundle<HelloWorldConfiguration>(
                    Company.class
            ) {
                @Override
                public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(
                        HelloWorldConfiguration configuration
                ) {
                    return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
                }
            };



    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<HelloWorldConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.addBundle(new SwaggerBundle<HelloWorldConfiguration>() {
            @Override
            protected SwaggerBundleConfiguration getSwaggerBundleConfiguration(HelloWorldConfiguration sampleConfiguration) {
                return sampleConfiguration.getSwaggerBundleConfiguration();
            }
        });
        bootstrap.addBundle(hibernateBundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(HelloWorldConfiguration configuration,
                    Environment environment) {

        final CompanyDAO companyDAO = new CompanyDAO(hibernateBundle.getSessionFactory());
        environment.jersey().register(new CompaniesResource(companyDAO));
        environment.jersey().register(new JsonProcessingExceptionMapper(true));
    }

}
```

Configuration class:

```
public class HelloWorldConfiguration extends Configuration {

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private DataSourceFactory database = new DataSourceFactory();

    @NotNull
    private SwaggerBundleConfiguration swaggerBundleConfiguration;


    @JsonProperty("swagger")
    public void setSwaggerBundleConfiguration (SwaggerBundleConfiguration conf) {
        this.swaggerBundleConfiguration = conf;
    }

    @JsonProperty("swagger")
    public SwaggerBundleConfiguration getSwaggerBundleConfiguration () {
        return swaggerBundleConfiguration;
    }

    @JsonProperty("database")
    public void setDataSourceFactory(DataSourceFactory factory) {
        this.database = factory;
    }

    @JsonProperty("database") 
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
        return database;
    }

}
```

Resource class:

```
@Path("/companies")
@Api("Companies")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CompaniesResource {
    private CompanyDAO companyDAO;

    public CompaniesResource(CompanyDAO companyDAO) {
        this.companyDAO = companyDAO;
    }

    @GET
    @ApiOperation(
            value = "Gives list of all companies",
            response = Company.class,
            code = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
    )
    @UnitOfWork
    public List<Company> findAll () {
        return companyDAO.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @UnitOfWork
    public Optional<Company> getById(@PathParam("id") LongParam id) {
        return companyDAO.findById(id.get());
    }
}
```

I would be happy for any responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your json marshaller is not able to marshall google's Optional class. Try to return Company from the controller, and not Optional:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@UnitOfWork
public Company getById(@PathParam("id") LongParam id) {
    return companyDAO.findById(id.get()).get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and stopping me from beating my head to wall. I tried like you told and noticed that there was no get()-method for Optional class, which made me realize that I had wrong class imported. I had imported jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Optional, and the correct one was com.google.common.base.Optional.

Comment: Glad it somehow helped.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the error ***Unable to Process JSON***.
Troubleshooted more than 4 hours until I found the problem.

#### The error is caused because of Enum getter.

If you are using Enum fields/getters/setters in your POJO, Jackson will fail to map your JSON to Java Object, and it will crash, leading to the mentioned error.

Comment: Not exactly true. You can use @JsonProperty (com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation) on your enums and pass a valid String representation to allow your POJO to have Enum values.