# How to debug "Unable to process JSON" error, while calling my web-service using Postman?

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, dropwizard

I have created a Web Service using Dropwizard.
This is my **POJO**, which has almost 25 fields -

```
public class HelloWorld {
@NotEmpty
private String foo;
@NotEmpty
private String bar;
@NotEmpty
private String baz;
.. 
.. 

public HelloWorld() {
}

public UserRegistration(String foo, String bar, String baz,....)
{
 this.foo = foo;
 this.bar = bar;
 this.baz = baz;
 ..
 ..
 ..
}

public String getfoo() {
 return foo;
}

public String getbar() {
 return bar;
}

public String getbaz() {
 return baz;
}
public void setfoo(String foo) {
 this.foo = foo;
}

public void setbar(String bar) {
 this.bar = bar;
}
public void setbaz(String baz) {
 this.baz = baz;
}

}
```

Now when I am trying to call my API using postman, which uses my POJO -
body :-

```
{
      "Foo": "a",
      "bar": "b",
      "baz": "c",
       ..
       ..
 }
```

I get the following response :

```
{
"code": 400,
"message": "Unable to process JSON"
}
```

I have referred to the following links :

- [dropwizard-jersey-is-giving-unable-to-process-json-message-on-get-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773254/dropwizard-jersey-is-giving-unable-to-process-json-message-on-get-request)
- [Jackson Exception](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-exception)
- [Dropwizard Issues](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1612)

**I understand that Jackson is not able to convert this JSON to my POJO, due to some fields, but error message is not showing the culprit.**

**So can someone give me a way to debug this error in an efficient manner??**

Technologies using:-

- Dropwizard
- Jersey
- Jackson for serialization/deserialization

Comment: Post the real code. Post the real JSON. Post the complete and exact stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Server logs should give you more info about the error. 
If your class is similar to the `HeloWorld` example above, then I can already spot some errors. For example: field name `foo` getter/setter `getfoo()`/`setfoo(...)`, your JSON payload on postman has a field named `Foo`. This won't work automatically. It should be: getter/setter `getFoo()`/`setFoo(...)` (note the uppercase F). Your JSON payload on postman should have a field named `foo` (lowercase).